# Load sections of a css file depending on the browser

Tags: css, cross-browser

There are buttons on my website that look overly skinny in Chrome compared to Firefox.
 The button's HTML looks like:
 `<button name="shutdown" type="submit" value="df" class="boton"> Press </button>`

My CSS attempt looks like:

```
.boton {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #000;
    background: #ee3333;
    background: rgba(225, 50, 50, 0.6) !important;
    font-family: lucida console;
    border: 1px solid #FF4444;
    padding: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.chrome .boton
{
    padding: 5px !important;
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. ".boton" does indeed change the style of the button, but the padding doesn't change in Chrome. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the padding isn't applying to the element is due to the fact that there is no    `chrome` class assigned to any element. There are various hacks around certain Vendor-Specific styles, see [this article](http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/), but no browser applies a class of `.chrome` or `.moz` or anything like that.

However, to achieve more "horizontal" padding, you can use the `-webkit-padding-start`(padding-left) and the `-webkit-padding-end`(padding-right). Currently I do not believe there is full padding, or vertical padding for these yet. Be sure when using these to write the `-webkit-padding-start`, or whichever rule you use, after your `padding` rule. Otherwise the latter will overwrite the former and both will be lost.

Comment: I thought what I did was weird too, but I got it from this article: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/ and his demo works.

Comment: nevermind, I hadn't read that it requires a javascript code at the top

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've also added some browser sniffing that adds the class `.chrome` etc. to the body that class has no effect.

On the other hand the box model of Firefox and Chrome is not radically different, but the defaults for padding, border, margins etc. may be different. Just explicitly set those values and they should most likely render the same (give or take a few pixels because of different rounding errors). You should not need to add custom css for each browser (but if you use experimental css features like `-moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius` with vendor prefixes you should use all of them in at the same time; the others will ignore the unknown properties).

The different versions of IE (Internet Explorer) *do have* a radically different box models, and if you cannot get some version of IE to render something correctly with the standard css you should use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to include IE specific css overrides after the main css file.